# AAR in Eclipse ANT project

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, aar

is there any way to use .aar library (with resources) in eclipse ant project? I know that there is no simply way to use .aar format like in gradle, but maybe there is some workaround to unzip it and import it manually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This solution was helpful for me

**EDIT:** A .aar file is simply a zip file with the following contents:

1. AndroidManifest.xml (Required file)
2. classes.jar (required file)
3. Res / (compulsory folder)
4. R.txt (Required file)
5. Assets / (Optional folder)
6. libs/*.jar (folder option)
7. jni//*.so (optional folder)
8. proguard.txt (optional file)
9. lint.jar (optional file)

You see, within the .aar file you have everything you need to operate the library in eclipse.

to create library:

1. CREATE a new project (hereafter library project ) to your workspace. Do not forget to mark it as a library.
2. Leave empty src folder library project .
3. .aar Decompresses the file. You can rename it to .zip and unzip or
   use any tools.
4. Copy the file classes.jar into the libs file folder library project .
5. Res folder replaces the library project with .aar res file folder.
6. You've created the project that contains almost everything you need.

Now let's see how to configure your project to reference the library project.

1. In the project you want to use the library (henceforth, project goal ) added as the dependency library project .
2. Open AndroidManifest.xml .aar within the file and make sure to copy
   everything it takes (permits, activities, services, receivers ...)
   in the file AndroidManifest.xml project objective .
3. If there is, copy the entire contents of the folder assets .aar file in the assets folder target project .
4. If there is, copy the entire contents of the file .aar libs folder
   in folder libs target project .
5. Make a Clean the workspace and recompiled.

http://www.iphonedroid.com/blog/utilizar-ficheros-aar-en-eclipse/#.Vh3krye1Gko

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Onik Thank you, I will

Comment: Why I get -1 for the answer ?!

Comment: This answer certainly deserves a +1.

Comment: I did not create, new library project.  I just extract .aar file, copy the library from libs folder to libs folder to the project where i want to use and add to Build path, also copy manifest content, and res folder.  Now i'm able to reference/use lib.

Answer (score 14):

Indeed, aar files are just archive files. So you can unzip it and find jar files along with ressources files. The question have already been partially answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21485222/1836870

If you want to get the ressources inside your jar, you could try repackage like it's suggested in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21417599/1836870

Comment: how to unzip aar in Mac?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal , this is a simple zip archive. just change an extention. https://support.apple.com/kb/ph19072?locale=en_US

Answer (score 2):

The brunt of the work can be done by a wonderful script called [deaar](https://gist.github.com/commonsguy/a3a534ea28ef8a82a213). The gist explains things, but basically you run:

```
ruby deaar.rb [path/to/aar] [output_directory]
```

It outputs an almost ready to use library. Next, you need to run:

```
cd [output_directory]
android update lib-project -p . -t android-xx
```

Replace xx with the Android version you're targeting. Now put that directory where your build.xml and project.properties are. Finally, add a line like this to your project.properties:

```
android.library.reference.1=./output_directory
```

Replace the directory name with the one you created. You can use ".2" and so on for additional libraries. And that's it!

Comment: This made it possible for me to build a Google VR application within an Android ant project! Just a note that should be clear, there is one step that must be done to correctly integrate the library and it's that a given aar won't have any project.propertiesyou must be sure to have one and set android.library=true (in other case you'll get an UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION with classes.jar when building the project - thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/19332059/939781 )

Comment: The `android update lib-project` line given above will create the project.properties for you.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Fabric(Crashlytics) has a kits-libs plugin for dependencies management http://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/eclipse.html.

And there's another gradle plugin project https://github.com/ksoichiro/gradle-eclipse-aar-plugin.

Comment: Sadly Fabric pulled out... 
*With Google dropping support for Eclipse, after much thought, we’ve decided to discontinue support for Eclipse. We recommend switching to Android Studio.*