# Google play service library , not found in Eclipse directory folder

Tags: android, google-maps, eclipse-plugin, google-play-services

i am using eclipse to create apps,recently i had installed Google play service using sdk manager.but i didn't found any library in the installed location, i had searched for a solution in web and also re installing it! But, till yet i didn't get a solution to add Google play library into my project, kindly help me to come through .and also give any tips to add library in other ways

Answer (score 0):

you can not get the library project from SDK location but you can get .aar file of google play service from YourSDKLocation -> extras -> google -> m2repository -> com -> google -> android -> gms -> play service and Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33117095/8080277) steps to create library project from .aar

you can also download the library project from [here](https://github.com/vizZ/google-play-services_lib).