# How to integrate FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) without Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an Android App managed by CMake and built with Ant and I would like to integrate FCM in my App but all tutorials are using Android Studio(it is quite easy to do it with Android Studio but I am not going to migrate to Android Studio yet).
FCM provides libs only in .aar format which is meant for Android Studio. How to integrate it with CMake and Ant?

Comment: AAR files are not specific to Android Studio. But if your tooling can't parse the AAR file format, you can unpack it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777423/aar-in-eclipse-ant-project for a quick list of what they contain.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I actually read that thread and tried to split AAR into jar + res. Every thing was fine but than I failed to generate R.java for resources of FCM(it use R.string.xxx somewhere) in Ant "codegen" phase, which lead to runtime exception when FirebaseApp was initialized.

Comment: At this point you're most likely to get help if you [create a minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.